# sas proc http unknow host

Tags: http, sas, proc, unknown-host

```
filename rix "&input.\rix_eligible.xls";
proc http   method  =   "get" 
        url     =   "http://www.riksbank.se/Documents/Riksbanken/RIX/2014/Eligible%20assets.xls"
        out     =   rix;
run;
```

I try running this code and get an unknown host error in SAS.

Running the same code with a different url, to download another excel-spreadsheet works fine.

Can anyone tell me if they can download from this particular link and preferably give me a hint to what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Could be you're behind corporate proxy server?
Try options in PROC HTTP, e.g.

```
   proxyhost="proxyhost"
   proxyport=80
```

Could be `%20` is 'eaten' by SAS macro processor, but in that case it rather would be some 404 error. Try inside the url with single quotes.

Could be you need proxy authentication:

```
proxyusername="your-user-name"
proxypassword="your-password"
```

I'll also try using `curl` tool (http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) to help you find the problem.

Comment: Yes single-quotes are definitely required at a minimum.  Whether or not this will fix the issue is unknown.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did the following:

Comment: Adding single quotes ('%20' and adding proxyhost-ip does not solve the issue). I still get a unknown host.
I'm curious if anyone have tried downloading the file at the actual link I posted.
Could it be some firewall-thing at riksbank.se? If I grab it manually through a internet-browser I don't have any problems and I guess that the method ought to be the same (HTTP GET in both cases).